# LinqToEntities not retrieving child objects of an entity

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying out Linq for the first time and having a bit of difficult retrieving the child objects of an entity. I have a course table which has a one to many relationship with the department table (ie. one department can have one or many courses).

When I select the a particular department I want to bind the courses relating to that particular department to a gridview however the coursecount variable always returns a zero even when there are many courses related to that particular department. The dept object seems to be populated correctly apart from the courses objects.

Am I missing something obvious?

```
int deptid = Convert.ToInt32(cboDepartmentList.SelectedValue);
Department dept = schoolcontext.Department.First(p=> p.DepartmentID  == deptid);
int coursecourse = dept.Course.Count;
gvCourse.DataSource = dept.Course;
gvCourse.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
gvCourse.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

schoolcontext.Department.Include("Course").First...

EDIT: the above is the quick answer... more details are [here](http://www.singingeels.com/Blogs/Nullable/2008/10/27/EntityFramework_Include_Equivalent_in_LINQ_to_SQL.aspx) if you want them.